# Check if app is installed otherwise open webapp in HTML share link

Tags: javascript, web-applications, hyperlink, share

I have a share link to Telegram on my website for example, so for the user there is two possibilities :
Telegram APP is installed (Android or Windows desktop).
Telegram is not installed so the link must open to WEBAPP telegram (Android or desktop also)

Here are the link share for both :

```
https://t.me/share/url?url=URLTOSHARE
tg://msg_url?text=URLTOSHARE
```

what the best practise to make this link open installed app first (Android, Windows etc) and then open the webapp if not the local app is not installed.
I think in my case i don't need to know if user is on mobile or desktop because the first link open WEB TELEGRAM on both devices and second one open INSTALLED APP on both devices also.

Comment: The first link will open the app if it is installed, however not always. As far as my personal experience: the Firefox Android app for instance still opens links like that itself, and doesn't send them to Android OS. The second link only works if the app is installed. I'm also relatively sure that it's still not possible to find out if the app is installed, so what websites like instagram do is use the https link everywhere but also display an "open in app" button that uses the app protocol. I'm not 100% sure about any of this though, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @ChrisG yes but not all app will treat the link as IG does for example, and in my webpage there is a bunch of services to share to, for this reason i can't rely on IG or FB behaviour only, ... in my case the first links is reiable 100% but most of users on mobile want their installed app to be used instead of Web one, Thanks

Comment: I just did a quick test and in Firefox, the first link sends me to the telegram website, the second opens the app, as expected. If I click the first link in Chrome, it asks me whether to open it in Firefox (my default browser) or Telegram. Anyway, what I'm trying to say is that I would offer both links to your users. As in "Share" and "Share in app" or something. I also tried `tgh://` and an unknown protocol apparently does nothing. Firefox doesn't event blink, Chrome just refreshes the page, looks like.

Comment: @ChrisG apparently you re right for the first comment, the purpose is to put a link to the web api which will check if you have the app installed or not, it's the commen practice for all IM Apps, not all but most, ... i can't accept your comment until you put it as an answer .. thanks